# scaling algorithm of deeptools

Tags: deeptools

I am using [deeptools](https://deeptools.readthedocs.io) to generate a [metagene](https://deeptools.readthedocs.io/en/develop/content/feature/metagene.html) plot. I am wondering how the deeptools scale genes if the size of genes is shorter than bin size. For example, if my bin size is 1000 bp and the gene is about 450bp, how does the deeptools computeMatrix scale it to make a metagene plot of 1000 bp?